# JUnit test scanning folder class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mkdir

I want write several tests, but from a high level each of them should populate a directory structure with some files. I'd test each of these cases at least:

A single folder with a file that passes the filter.
A single folder with a file that does NOT pass the filter.
A nested folder with a file in each.

**Code:**

```
class FolderScan implements Runnable {

    private String path;
    private BlockingQueue<File> queue;
    private CountDownLatch latch;
    private File endOfWorkFile;
    private List<Checker> checkers;

    FolderScan(String path, BlockingQueue<File> queue, CountDownLatch latch,
            File endOfWorkFile) {
        this.path = path;
        this.queue = queue;
        this.latch = latch;
        this.endOfWorkFile = endOfWorkFile;
        checkers = new ArrayList<Checker>(Arrays.asList(new ExtentionsCheker(),
                new ProbeContentTypeCheker(), new CharsetDetector()));
    }

    public FolderScan() {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        findFiles(path);
        queue.add(endOfWorkFile);
        latch.countDown();
    }

    private void findFiles(String path) {
        boolean checksPassed = true;
        File root;

        try {
            root = new File(path);
            File[] list = root.listFiles();
            for (File currentFile : list) {
                if (currentFile.isDirectory()) {
                    findFiles(currentFile.getAbsolutePath());
                } else {
                    for (Checker currentChecker : checkers) {
                        if (!currentChecker.check(currentFile)) {
                            checksPassed = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (checksPassed)
                        queue.put(currentFile);
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong input !!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

- How to create files into each folder?
- To prove that queue contains
  the File objects that you expect?
- The last element in queue is the
  'trigger' File?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to create files into each folder?

- Extract the file IO and use a mocked repository for the tests. This means that you will have the IO somewhere else and may wish to use the below to test that.
- A temp folder using the [JUnit rule](http://junit-team.github.com/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html) With a test folder you create the files to match the test.

> To prove that queue contains the File objects that you expect?

.equals works well for File objects I believe.

> A single folder with a file that does NOT pass the filter.

I'd pass in the blockers so I can pass in an "Always Pass" and "Always Fail" blocker.

```
public class TestFolderScan {
        @Rule
        public TemporaryFolder folder= new TemporaryFolder();

        @Test
        public void whenASingleFolderWithAFileThatPassesTheFilterThenItExistsInTheQueue() {
                File expectedFile = folder.newFile("file.txt");
                File endOfWorkFile = new File("EOW");
                Queue queue = ...;
                FolderScan subject = new FolderScan(folder.getRoot(), queue, new AllwaysPassesBlocker(),...);

                subject.run();

                expected = new Queue(expectedFile, endOfWorkFile);
                assertEquals(queue, expected);
        }
}
```

Comment: What does `new AllwaysPassesBlocker(),` mean? Which is type `expected`?

Comment: It means you pass in your "Blockers" to a new constructor and you create a new "Blocker" that always passes.
Expected is a BlockingQueue<File>.

Comment: Can you write? Coz I didn't caught.

Comment: Sorry "Checker" not "Blocker". Create new ctor that takes a list of "Checkers". Write new Checker that just returns true.

Comment: Does this constructor add to the `FolderScan`? Right.

Comment: Yes a new ctor on FolderScan. What you want to be able to do is set FolderScan up so that you can control every aspect of it. At the moment you can not as "Checker"s are created within the FolderScan object.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26103/discussion-between-nazar-art-and-mlk)