# Refactoring scanning folder class (add AllwaysPassesBlocker())

Tags: java, refactoring

I need create a new constructor in `FolderScan` that takes a list of **"Checkers"**. And all these "Checkers" always `return true` (schoud write new **Chekers** List that just return true.)
But problem is that I don't know how do this and not decompose structure of program.

**Code (FolderScan and each Cheker):**

```
class FolderScan implements Runnable {

    FolderScan(String path, BlockingQueue<File> queue, CountDownLatch latch,
            File endOfWorkFile) {
        this.path = path;
        this.queue = queue;
        this.latch = latch;
        this.endOfWorkFile = endOfWorkFile;

        checkers = new ArrayList<Checker>(Arrays.asList(
                new ExtentionChecking(),  new ProbeContentTypeCheking(), 
                new EncodingChecking() ));
    }

        @Override
public void run() {
    try {
        findFiles(path);
        queue.put(endOfWorkFile);
        latch.countDown();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    private void findFiles(String path) {

    try {
        File root = new File(path);
        File[] list = root.listFiles();
        for (File currentFile : list) {
            boolean checksPassed = true;
            if (currentFile.isDirectory()) {
                findFiles(currentFile.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                for (Checker currentChecker : checkers) {
                    if (!currentChecker.check(currentFile)) {
                        checksPassed = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (checksPassed) {
                    queue.put(currentFile);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    private String path;
    private BlockingQueue<File> queue;
    private CountDownLatch latch;
    private File endOfWorkFile;
    private List<Checker> checkers;
}

class ExtentionChecking implements Checker {

    @Override
    public boolean check(File currentFile) {
        fileName = currentFile.getName().toLowerCase();
        Set<String> extensions = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(".txt",
                ".pdf", ".doc", ".docx", ".html", ".htm", ".xml", ".djvu",
                ".djv", ".rar", ".rtf", ".tmp"));

        if (extensions.contains(fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".")))) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private String fileName;
}

class EncodingChecking implements Checker {

    @Override
    public boolean check(File currentFile) {
        return detectEncoding(currentFile);
    }

    public static boolean detectEncoding(File file) {
        detector = new CharsetDetector();

        // validate input
        if (null == file) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("input file can't be null");
        }
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "input file refers to a directory");
        }

        // read input file
        byte[] buffer;
        try {
            buffer = readUTFHeaderBytes(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Can't read input file, error = " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        if(detector.setText(buffer) != null){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static byte[] readUTFHeaderBytes(File input) throws IOException {
        // read data
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(input);
        try {
            byte firstBytes[] = new byte[50];
            int count = fileInputStream.read(firstBytes);
            if (count < 5) {
                throw new IOException("Poor file!");
            }
            return firstBytes;
        } finally {
            fileInputStream.close();
        }
    }


    private static CharsetDetector detector;
}



class ProbeContentTypeCheking implements Checker {

    @Override
    public boolean check(File currentFile) {
        String mimeType = null;
        try {
            Path path = Paths.get(currentFile.getAbsolutePath());
            byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            MagicMatch match = Magic.getMagicMatch(data);
            mimeType = match.getMimeType();
        } catch (MagicParseException | MagicMatchNotFoundException
                | MagicException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (null != mimeType) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**Question:**

- How do refactor this code - after this able to make `new
  AllwaysPassesBlocker()` and all **Checers** return true?

Comment: That is too much code with less/unclear explanation.

Comment: I cannot find the code that actually calls the checkers and does things with that queue and the latch. Can you add that?

Comment: @flup I updated part of code. If need can add creations CountDownLatch & Executor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A checker that always returns true would be

```
class UncriticalChecker implements Checker {
    @Override
    public boolean check(File currentFile) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

There's no point adding such a checker to the list of checkers, though. You might as well leave the list empty.

I don't quite see why the checkers should be constructed in the constructor of the FolderScan. It seems more natural to pass them to the constructor as an argument.

```
FolderScan(String path, BlockingQueue<File> queue, CountDownLatch latch,
        File endOfWorkFile, List<Checker> checkers) {
    this.path = path;
    this.queue = queue;
    this.latch = latch;
    this.endOfWorkFile = endOfWorkFile;
    this.checkers = checkers;
}
```

Then, when you initialize the FolderScan, pass it the checkers

```
List<Checker> checkers = new ArrayList<Checker>(Arrays.asList(
            new ExtentionChecking(),  new ProbeContentTypeCheking(), 
            new EncodingChecking() ));
FolderScan folderScan = 
    new FolderScan(path, queue, latch, endOfWorkFile, checkers);
```

Or, if you wish to create a FolderScan that returns all files, you pass it an empty list.

```
FolderScan folderScan =
    new FolderScan(path, queue, latch, endOfWorkFile, Collections.emptyList());
```

EDIT:
I now understand that you wish to test the class. Then the UncriticalChecker makes sense.  If you want to test the code with a checker that always says yes, pass it to the constructor:

```
List<Checker> checkers = Collections.singletonList(new UncriticalChecker());
FolderScan folderScan = 
    new FolderScan(path, queue, latch, endOfWorkFile, checkers);
```

Comment: This need for Folder Scan testing. According with [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199786/junit-test-scanning-folder-class). I nor sure about this `UncriticalChecker`.

Comment: Ah! This new constructor is the same that got suggested in that answer too:   
  
Yes a new ctor on FolderScan. What you want to be able to do is set FolderScan up so that you can control every aspect of it. At the moment you can not as "Checker"s are created within the FolderScan object. – mlk yesterday

Comment: UncriticalChecker was the name I made up for a checker that accepts all files.